# Cursor Loader reloads on orientation change

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cursorloader, android-loadermanager

I see similar questions here but mine is different. I have an Activity with a Cursor LoaderManager. I am using a switch statement inside onCreateLoader and onLoadFinished because I am dealing with three different CursorLoaders. So far so good. The problem is that on orientation change the loaders are requerying for their respective data. I am using minSdkVersion 11 and support library.  How do I prevent the requerying from happening? (I have no Internet so am using cellphone to post. So no code, but explanation should be clear to those who understand loaders)

Answer (score 0):

If you put your initLoader in one of the lifecycle's activity/fragment creation method and use a CursorAdapter, you will have that behavior.

The adapter you have is using the cursor to display its data and, as everything is destroyed on rotation, it has to get that data again (which comes from the cursor that was also destroyed).

If you want to get ride of the reloading I would suggest to populate a list and use a regular adapter. That way you could just save the list and restore it on rotation, and pass it again to the adapter.